# How to write query in JPQL?

Tags: java, database, jpa, jpql

I have a three classes: Doctor, Patient and Consultation.
Both Doctor and Patient classes have a list of consultations as field.

```
@Entity
public class Consultation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private Calendar scheduleDate;
    private String information;
    private String symptoms;
    @ManyToOne
    private Doctor doctor;
    @ManyToOne
    private Patient patient;
//...
}

@Entity
public class Patient {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String ssn;
    private String address;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient")
    private List<Consultation> consultations;
//...
}

@Entity
public class Doctor  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String specialization;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor")
    private List<Consultation> consultations;
//...
}
```

I want to obtain the patients of a doctor from a single query; that is all the patients that have the same consultation as a doctor. Note that there is no connection between Doctor and Patient.
Is this posible?

```
select p from Patient p where p.consultations **someKeyword** (select d.consultations from Doctor d where d.id = :doctorId)
```

If I'm not mistaken *someKeyword* would be *contains* if there would be

```
where list<entity> contains entity
```

and *in* if

```
where entity in list<entity>
```

but in this case there would be

```
list someKeyword list
```

A combination would be:

```
select p from Patient p where p.consultations contains (select c from Consultation c where c in (select d.consultations from Doctor d where d.id = :doctorId))
```

but does this make sens?

I am a beginner in JPA and JPQL.

Comment: I have found work around; I get all the Consultations and then the patient from each consultation. Still, I would like to know if something like what's abouve makes sens / is posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
select p from Patient p
where exists (
    select c from Consultation c
    where c.patient = p
    and c.doctor.id = :doctorId
)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial might help:
[JPA Tutorial](http://www.java-forums.org/ocpjbcd/53461-tutorial-review-java-persistence-query-language-component-developer-exam.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NamedQuery annotation which looks something like below

```
@NamedQuery(
   name = "findPatientForDoctor", 
   query = "SELECT c.patient FROM Consultation c WHERE c.doctor.id : id"))
```

(just check for the syntax of this query alone)

This will give one patient for a doctor id.

Since your association is like Patient have consultations and each consutlation has one to one mapping with Patient and Doctor. Currently there is no relation in your entity model to get all the patients for a doctor. Patient to Doctor is a many to many relation and currently your entity seems not supporting that. I dont think without a patient to doctor relation you can get the records in one single query.